# Append certain outputs to file linux

Tags: linux, script

I have a cron job updating Wordpress plug-ins using the wp-cli command.
Then writing the output to a file by appending wp-cli-log.txt
When I run the company manually, usually I get the output ‘Success: Plugin already updated.’
I don’t want my log file to fill up with that output, only to add the relevant update info when plugins actually get updated.
Can I do this via a script? And if so, how do I achieve it??

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is nothing to do with electronic design.

Comment: Thanks, I posted from my phone and didn’t check where I was posting cause I’m less than intelligent :s sorry for that

Comment: Very much sounds like a case for `grep -vF "Success: Plugin already updated."` in the pipeline. Could you show the full command you are using to write the file as of now?

Comment: i currently have a script containing >

#!/bin/bash
phrase="Success: Plugin already updated."
output="$(wp plugin update --all --path=/var/www/website)"
if [[ $output != $phrase ]]; then
echo "$output" >> /var/www/website/bashoutput.txt
fi
exit 0

Comment: Sounds good. So you replace `>` by `| grep -vF "Success: Plugin already updated." >`

Comment: so i could use a command : wp plugin update --all --path=/var/www/website | grep -vF "Success: Plugin already updated." >> wp-cli-log.txt

Comment: Yes, that should work as wanted